# Kafka Monitoring With New Relic

Tags: apache-kafka, monitoring, newrelic

**Problem:** There's a random consumer lag in multi regional consumers and I can't figure out why and I can't get decent information from New Relic.

**Context** ~
I have some Kafka consumers in 2 different regions and there's significant latency between these 2 regions. Let's say Region A and Region B.
Most of my services are in Region B, including my Kafka producers, brokers and some consumers. Some consumers are in Region A. But, when they consume, they still have to make call to Region B because my database resides in Region B

Last week, my kafka consumers saw a huge lag for 3 consecutive days and then it came back to normal. I checked logs, no 5xx or 4xx errors. As a matter of fact, everything was 200.
I'm trying to build some graphs in New Relic to see how often my consumers are consuming the messages in different regions. The problem is that the new relic is setup to get metrics from the broker and it has information about offset and whatnot for consumers. When I construct any query, it will show everything under 1 region. The only difference I can see is the IP address of my consumers, which should be good enough to create a graph and see how many messages which consumer consumed in what time.

**What I did** ~
I wrote this query
`SELECT rate(average(`consumer.offset`), 1 day) FROM KafkaOffsetSample FACET topic, clientHost TIMESERIES AUTO`
But, the graph that I get from this seem wrong. Because offset keeps on increasing (which makes sense). If the consumers recovered after 3 days, then this offset value should go down as well. Well, at least that is my understanding.

The templates NewRelic has are pretty much useless. Bytes in and out... but nothing on the offsets and relations of consumers and producers.

Comment: If you want to measure lag, you need to instrument the consumers, or use a tool like Burrow, then export that to NewRelic somehow... Sounds like you're querying broker metrics, which give you no client information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn’t enough info here to determine whether this is network related.  Lag caused by suboptimal network performance is not uncommon.  No sure if that’s the case here.

There’s a possibility that you may need client side metrics, broker side (which it sounds like what you have) isn’t going to likely get what you want in this case.

Also, the specific integration they are using, isn’t what NR uses internally to monitor so unfortunately there’s not much expertise internally on what information may be available.

The Java agent does have some built in Kafka client instrumentation that may help but there isn’t much by way of dashboards available AFAIK and it likely won’t help without some targeted queries.